# Can i Use the value of a variable from within a ruby script inside ssh.exec()

Tags: ruby, net-ssh

If i have a  `# {}` , like  `#{results}`, in the snippet below:

```
results = Array.new
f = open("/Users/kahmed/messages", "r")                                  
f.each_line do |line| 
  results << "#{$.} #{line}" if line =~ /NFE/                                      
  puts #{results}
end
```

How can i use it in the following ssh.exec command

```
Net::SSH.start( HOST, USER, :password => PASS ) do|ssh|                              
  ssh.exec(#{results})
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Net::SSH.start( HOST, USER, :password => PASS ) do|ssh| 
  results.each{|line| ssh.exec( line)}
end
```